# Get root node from DOM Document class

Tags: php, domdocument

I am trying to get the root node of a PHP DOM Document. This is usually done by doing something like this:

```
$doc->documentElement;
```

However, trying this on a HTML string that contains a doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...
```

and that is loaded into a DOM Document object like so:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

returns the root node as the `html` tag and not the doctype tag! I am guessing this because of the weird characters `<!`- is there anyway to return the root node correctly?

Comment: [It's called "element type name", dammit.](http://www.flightlab.com/~joe/sgml/faq-not.txt). :-) The `DOCTYPE` declaration is an SGML construct that is not part of the document grammar itself. The root *element* is indeed the `html` element. In general, SGML declarations are things that look like `<!**** >`, where `****` is some keyword, and those are *not* part of the document tree. The only declarations that can appear in the top level are the doctype declaration, comment declarations `<!-- -->`, notation declarations (and perhaps marked sections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctype isn't the root node, `html` is. The doctype is simply the doctype declaration that tells the browser what the rest of the file is.

Maybe you can use DOMDocument::doctype ? (`$doc -> doctype`)

Comment: I tried to use the doctype object to reconstruct the doctype but it doesn't give me back everything just some components. But I understand now, doctype isn't the root node. I'll just stick to my regex to get the doc type back.

Answer (score 0):

the `DOCTYPE` is not actually a node, and it certainly isn't the root node.  Try `$doc->doctype`.

Comment: The DOCTYPE is a Node (he inherits from DOMNode): `$doc->firstChild->...->nodeType === XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE`. [w3: Node::DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem some time ago and it was because I actually didn't want the `DOCTYPE` in there at all. I was using code snippets and was having a hard time getting the returned values to be untainted with `DOCTYPE` and HTML tags added when there shouldn't be.

I am going to present an answer not in here yet just in case your having the same problem I had. My solution actually prevents the adding of any `DOCTYPE` elements if you have a newer version of php. I believe it's a minimum of PHP v5.4 and up and also LibXML v2.7.8 minimum. If you have both of these versions up to date then its as simple as adding a constant flag to the method call of the DOMDocument object's loadHTML implementation. The constant is `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` and it is used like this....

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($someContentString, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

This way there is no additional parsing needed at all and you can go about your life without this `DOCTYPE` problem... unless you needed the `DOCTYPE` tag in which case my answer and let someone else find it through Google :)